# Tweak code to add ascending number to each cell in a column to last row starting on 2nd row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Sub to add ascending number to each cell in a column to last row starting on 2nd row
but row two starts on `2` I need it to start on `1` and I can not figure out how to get the 2nd row to start on 1 and count down to last row

Thanks

```
Sub AutoCount()

Dim LR As Long

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("L2:L" & LR).Formula = "=ROW(L2)"

End Sub
```

Comment: How about `"=ROW(L2)-1"`?

Comment: Why don't you post this as the answer? I misunderstood the question and posted a different answer. Yours is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `"=ROW(L2)"`, use `"=ROW(L2)-1"`.

Comment: Thanks Jack that works, I continued trying and this work as well `Range("L2:L" & LR).Formula = "=ROW(L1)"`